# In Django admin, how to prevent deletion of last object of a type

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way I can prevent the user from deleting the last object of a certain type (i.e. the last row in the table)? They should still be able to delete that kind of object generally, but it must be ensured that there's always at least one entry left - in this particular case, at least one entry associated with the user.

I tried overriding the model's delete function:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    others = Presentation.objects.filter(user=self.user).exclude(pk=self.pk)
    if len(others) < 1:
        pass
    else:
        super(Presentation, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works, but the user is told that the deletion was actually successful. I'd rather like an error message to be displayed, like when validation fails. Validation only applies to saving, however, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this too please?

```
# admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
         if last_record:
              storage = messages.get_messages(request)
              storage.used = True
              messages.error(request, 'Cannot delete last record.')
         else:
              obj.delete()
```

Another option could be to hide the success message div or span with jQuery.

Comment: This didn't work. `clean()` is apparently called on save, but not on delete.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. No reason to clean anything on delete. My bad.

Comment: Hmm, this includes the messaging framework. I tried it this way, but `message_set.create()` has been removed in django 1.4 (and is deprecated in 1.3, I believe). It worked with this line: `messages.error(request, 'Cannot delete last record.')`. This will display an error message on the page to which one is redirected after deletion, on top of the success message; this is a bit confusing, but better than nothing. Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Yes, although I didn't use the storage part.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you another approach:

1) Create and connect a signal to pre_delete and raise and exception on your condition:

```
def on_delete(sender,**kwargs):
    if <condition>:
        raise Exception('Abort delete')
    #else: continue and delete

pre_delete.connect(on_delete,sender=Presentation)
```

2) Then, on the view, you can catch this exception

```
# view code...
try:
    object.delete()
except:
    # add the desired info to context
```

Anyway, you can also override `model::delete` to throw the exception and catch it in the view code.

Comment: what do you mean with "on the view"? I don't use a custom view, but the built-in django admin views, and the built-in templates. Would I have to write a custom view & use a custom template for this?

Comment: If you are **ONLY** using this in admin with built-in views and templates, then dan-klasson's approach is better since form errors are already shown in admin templates.... but be careful, cause any other delete operation not through this admin form will not check your condition :S